# Is it possible to get the previous channel or point to point messages sent using Signalling API?

Tags: agora.io

I would like to use Agora Signalling SDK to create a chat app.

I am aware that I can use the `onMessageChannelReceive` and `onMessageInstantReceive` callbacks to receive messages that were sent.

Is it possible to get messages that were sent previously? If a user logouts and logs in back, is there a way to get the messages that were sent previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Agora Signaling SDK does not support persistent messages. There is a new Realtime Messaging SDK that is in beta that will have more robust features. I would recommend you reach out to the Agora.io team to get more information because I think it will help with your use case.